# Kafka 0.8.2 custom API libraries?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka queue 0.8.2 and have implemented standard poll and push calls. Now wanna go to pollByIndex methods that require implementation of Simple Consumer.

Does somebody knows some custom library which already deals with methods like this since implementing Simple Consumer can be a lot of work :)

Upgrading to 0.9 to use ConsumerAPI not option yet for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So creating SimpleConsumer is not really easy. So I went for solution of implementing another command that creates different group each time I queue for results which is stored in zookeeper and then assign offset I need on topic. That way default streaming queue will not be destroyed, it create small load on zookeeper but nothing significant.

Also after every querying I take care to remove group from zookeeper to keep it clean.

1 day of coding more less.

With new versions 0.9 and newer we will have ConsumerAPI which has its own calls also for this situation. Until then more work from dev side needed.